# Metadata components != number of destination bands Railo error when using cfimage

Tags: sql-server, google-maps, coldfusion, railo

I am trying to generate static maps in Railo (coldfusion) using  as follow:

```
<cfimage action = "write" destination = "#request.DataRoot#\map\#pickuppoint_Code#.jpeg" source = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C#Latitude#,#Longitude#"  quality = "1" overwrite = "yes">
```

After generating almost 250 maps it generates the following error:

```
Railo 4.1.1.002 Error (javax.imageio.IIOException)
Message     Metadata components != number of destination bands
Cause   javax.imageio.IIOException
Stacktrace  The Error Occurred in
C:\Web\wi_vigicolis.loc\Process\Task\Map\index.cfm: line 7

    5: <cfinclude template="qry_item.cfm">
    6: <cfloop query="GetPickuPointList">
    7: <cfimage action = "write" destination = "#request.DataRoot#\map\#pickuppoint_Code#.jpeg" source = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=15&size=300x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C#Latitude#,#Longitude#" quality = "1" overwrite = "yes">
```

I tried to add the API key but that did not solve the problem. I tried to execute the same code from another server, it generates also almost 250 maps only before generating the same error

Is it a limitation or a Railo problem ??

(I take the latitude and Longitude info from a database (sql server). I have to generate 8000 maps).

Thanks

Comment: This has been around for a while and is registered on the Railo bug tracker. Not sure if it will ever get resolved in Railo: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO-1849 You might be able to get around it by saving as a PNG instead of JPEG